# CakePHP Master/Slave change on demand

Tags: cakephp

How can I change useDbConfig for all models at once but have the option to change this at any time i want on the same action.

There are some plugins that look at the query, when it contains UPDATE, INSERT etc.. it will use the master database, and for selects it uses slaves..

But problem is that slave databases are always behind the master, and if there is a delay of 0.5 sec, it could be possible that the SELECT after an INSERT/UPDATE could not find what just updated..

For now the slaves are 0.05 sec behind the master, so thats fast.. but its behind! and if somehow the delay 0.5 sec it could be a problem.

When i have a shell like this:

ManagementShell
    function doHeavyCalculation($users) {

```
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $this->User->useDbConfig = 'slave1';
        // Do heavy sql calulation (use slave 1 db)

        $this->User->useDbConfig = 'slave2';
        // Do heavy sql subcalulations (use slave 2 db)

        $this->User->useDbConfig = 'master';
        // write data + some find queries (use master db)
    }
}
```

When i do it this way, it only changes the databaseconfig for the model User, and not for any related models.

Now does the User model have many relations.. I can do it like below.. but that is a never ending story.. and not the way it should.. dirty code..

```
foreach($users as $user) {

    $this->User->useDbConfig = 'slave1';
    $this->User->UserRelation->useDbConfig = 'slave1';
    $this->User->Group->SubGroupModel->useDbConfig = 'slave1';
    $this->User->Profile->useDbConfig = 'slave1';
    $this->User->Profile->Country->useDbConfig = 'slave1';
    $this->User->.........->useDbConfig = 'slave1';
    // Do heavy sql calulation (use slave1 db)

    $this->User->useDbConfig = 'master';
    $this->User->UserRelation->useDbConfig = 'master';
    $this->User->Group->SubGroupModel->useDbConfig = 'master';
    $this->User->Profile->useDbConfig = 'master';
    $this->User->Profile->Country->useDbConfig = 'master';
    $this->User->.........->useDbConfig = 'master';
    // write data + some find queries (use master db)

}
```

My ideal solution would be a simple call $this->User->setGlobalDatabase = 'slave1'; That all models use slave1 as database connection.

And with $this->User->setGlobalDatabase = 'master'; Now use Master for all models/queries. But that i can see in sql debug log on what server the sql queries are executed.

```
(master) 393 queries took .. ms
INSERT ...
SELECT ...
UPDATE ...
..

(slave1) 1351 queries took .. ms
SELECT ...
SELECT ...
..
```

There is also an option to change the current mysql connection. But then i dont see what is happend on slave1 and on master because in sql debug output is shows only the first connection (master)

I'm using CakePHP 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the database globally, rather than trying to change each model's database, I would suggest you either change AppModel's database, or change the DATABASE_CONFIG's $default property directly. Either way will save you a lot of trying to figure out which model is pointing where, and both will have the same end result.